# Error with displaying message after quiz ends , flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unoTW.png)

There are 3 questions in my app currently and as per my code after all my questions are answered one by one, a widget should appear on the screen which completely fills the screen and which should say " You did it". But unfortunately, I have been trying a lot and still can't find solution.

below is code for main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './quiz.dart';
import './result.dart'; 


//void main(){
//runApp(MyApp());
//}

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return _MyAppState();
  }
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final _questions = const [
    {
      'questionText': 'What\'s is your favourite color? ',
      'answers': ['Black', 'Red', 'Green', 'white'],
    },
    {
      'questionText': 'What\'s is your favourite animal?',
      'answers': ['Snake', 'Elephant', 'Lion'],
    },
    {
      'questionText': 'Who is your favourite instructor? ',
      'answers': ['Max', 'Max', 'Max', 'Max'],
    },

  ];
  var _questionIndex = 0;

  void _answerQuestion() {
    // var aBool= true;
    // aBool = false;

    setState(() {
      _questionIndex = _questionIndex;
    });
    print(_questionIndex);
    if (_questionIndex < _questions.length) {
      print('We have more questions!');
    } else {
      print('No more questions!');
    }
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
// var dummy =  ['Hello'];
// dummy.add('Max');
// print(dummy);
// dummy = [];
// questions = [];  

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('My First App'),
        ),
        body : _questionIndex <= 2
            ? Quiz(
              answerQuestion: _answerQuestion,
               questionIndex: _questionIndex,
                questions: _questions,


              )
              : Result(),

      ),
    );
  } 
}
```

below is code for question.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Question extends StatelessWidget {
  final String questionText;

  Question(this.questionText);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

                                return Container(
                                  width: double.infinity,
                                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                  child: Text(
                                  questionText,
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 28),
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    ),
    );
  }
}`
```

below id code for answer.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Answer extends StatelessWidget {
final Function selectHandler;
final String answerText;
  Answer(this.selectHandler, this.answerText);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      child:  RaisedButton(
       color: Colors.blue,
       textColor: Colors.white,
       child: Text(answerText),
       onPressed: selectHandler,
      ), 
    );
  }
}
```

below is code for quiz.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './question.dart';
import './answer.dart';

class Quiz extends StatelessWidget {
final List<Map<String, Object>>questions;
final int questionIndex;
final Function answerQuestion;

Quiz({
   @required this.questions, 
   @required this.answerQuestion, 
   @required this.questionIndex,
   });




  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
                children: [
                  Question(
                    questions[questionIndex]['questionText'],
                  ),
                  ...(questions[questionIndex]['answers'] as List<String>)
                      .map((answer) {
                    return Answer(answerQuestion, answer);
                  }).toList()
                ],
              );
  }
}
```

below is code for result.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class Result extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
                child: Text('You did it!'),
              );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please don't forget to mark the answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

The moment I fixed the following line, your app started working as you described. Going through each question and then showing the "You did it!" text.

```
setState(() {
  _questionIndex++;
});
```

You were just doing `_questionIndex = _questionIndex` before, which doesn't change any value.

Comment: Hi, i tried changing my code as you described above but it didn't seem to change anything.Moreover i found another problem which is that when I changed some answers to my question, i expected the changes to be seen in my app but that was not the case. So now when i change my question or answer it doesn't appear on my app. Help me please.

Comment: Someone else on another answer has also copied your code and changed only this line and it works, there's nothing else we can say. Regarding you changing your answers, are you using hot reload? It should just change as soon as you do.

Comment: TextAlign under questions file is also underlined, can that be affecting my app?

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting the error you mentioned,

Here what I did,

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final _questions = const [
    {
      'questionText': 'What\'s is your favourite color? ',
      'answers': ['Black', 'Red', 'Green', 'white'],
    },
    {
      'questionText': 'What\'s is your favourite animal?',
      'answers': ['Snake', 'Elephant', 'Lion'],
    },
    {
      'questionText': 'Who is your favourite instructor? ',
      'answers': ['Max', 'Max', 'Max', 'Max'],
    },
  ];

  var _questionIndex = 0;

  void _answerQuestion(String question, String selectedAnswer) {
    print("==============================================");
    print("QUESTION: $question");
    print("SELECTED ANSWER: $selectedAnswer");
    print("==============================================");
    setState(() {
      _questionIndex++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('My First App'),
        ),
        body: _questionIndex < _questions.length //TODO:
            ? Quiz(
                quizQuestion: _questions[_questionIndex]["questionText"],
                quizOptions: _questions[_questionIndex]["answers"],
                onAnswerSelect: _answerQuestion,
              )
            : Result(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Quiz extends StatelessWidget {
  final String quizQuestion;
  final List<String> quizOptions;
  final void Function(String, String) onAnswerSelect;

  Quiz({
    @required this.quizQuestion,
    @required this.quizOptions,
    @required this.onAnswerSelect,
  });

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Question(quizQuestion),
        ...quizOptions.map(
          (option) => Answer(
            answerText: option,
            selectHandler: () => onAnswerSelect(quizQuestion, option),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class Question extends StatelessWidget {
  final String questionText;

  Question(this.questionText);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: Text(
        questionText,
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 28),
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Answer extends StatelessWidget {
  final String answerText;
  final VoidCallback selectHandler;

  Answer({this.answerText, this.selectHandler});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      child: RaisedButton(
        color: Colors.blue,
        textColor: Colors.white,
        child: Text(answerText),
        onPressed: selectHandler,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Result extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Text('You did it!'),
    );
  }
}
```